# Upload File from Client to Server C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

Got an issue "Path Not Found" when try to upload an image from Client site to another server(Not the application server). The code is just like below:

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"xx.xx.xx.xx\" + FileUpload1.FileName));
```

The error occurred after i have deployed the application into the web application server. But when run locally successfully uploaded.

I suspect the File Uploader that run from the application server cannot found the path from client site. It is because the path of the image does not existed in the application server.

There are two question regarding this issue:

1) Is there anyway to resolved this issue.

2) Is there any differences between "`FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs()`" and `FileUpload1.SaveAs()`?

Thanks for trying to help me on this.

Comment: Do you have access of this server @"xx.xx.xx.xx\" ?
and what protocol you are using ?  You can upload via FTP Client if you have FTP access of that server.

Comment: you need to add a shared folder on that server

Comment: Yes this is asp.net.

Comment: I have created the shared folder in the destination server as mentioned before. - Thorarins

Yup, i have the access of this server. Currently i only tried by using File Upload only rather than other solutions to upload an image. By the way how to do that. Thanks - sm.abdullah

Comment: Does the IIS user account on the server have access to the remote shared drive, does it have write permissions? Remember the IIS service is probably not running under your user credentials

Comment: It was confirmed by the technical team that the user account given has the access to the remote server.
During the development phase, i am running the application by using the Visual Studio debug mode, the image was successfully been upload to the shared folder. But it becomes failed when the application is running from the application server (already deployed).

Comment: Give Full permisions in Security for the Shared folder

Comment: Full permission is already given. But the error still there. Actually, how can we read the full path by using the File Upload from the web application server? Seems it cannot found the images from client site.

Answer (score 0):

You should write path as `img.Save("c:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Barcodes\\1.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);`

Comment: Sorry, not really understand what are trying to advice here. Is it you want me to set the hardcoded path?